# roscd: No such package/stack 'turtlebot_navigation/'

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After following the tutorial in this link [click here](http://www.iroboapp.org/index.php?title=Adding_Relaxed_Astar_Global_Path_Planner_As_Plugin_in_ROS)
and go all the way down to ( Running the Plugin on the Turtlebot )

when i run this command `$ roscd turtlebot_navigation/`
i get in error say `roscd: No such package/stack 'turtlebot_navigation/'`

also when i run the other command   `$ cd launch/includes/`
i get in error say  `bash: cd: launch/includes/: No such file or directory`

In addition, Do i have to have the turtlebot robot to run the navigation

i really appreciate your help and time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216142/roscd:-no-such-package/stack-%27turtlebot_navigation/%27/) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check if the turtlebot pkgs have been released for Jade? I think the latest officially supported release is for indigo. Check this link: http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot

---

Originally posted by [staljbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/17761/staljbs/) with karma: 116 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-19**:
**Thank you for your help, can you please answer this question  [CLICK HERE](http://answers.ros.org/question/216143/how-to-make-a-robot-follow-a-line-in-ros/)**

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well `roscd: No such package/stack 'turtlebot_navigation/'` means the package

> turtlebot_navigation

is not installed.

You should be able to install it with `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-navigation`

The second error is a following error, because it expects your directory to be the one
of turtlebot_navigation now, but it could not be found... so you stay in the former directory and there is no
subdirectory called launch.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-19**:
**after following your instucrtion i get in error say**

```
 E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-turtlebot-navigation
```

**and my ROS version  is jade**